# Is Bitmap object held in memory by reference?

Tags: java, android, pointers, object, bitmap

Please forgive me for what is likely an incredibly cringeworthy question (I am quite new to both Java and Android Studio). I come from a C background and am currently developing a mobile app for Google Play using Android Studio. The application will require a number of enemy objects to be created for the game.

Consider the following method of creating a Bitmap for an enemy object;

Within the GamePanel class (parent is SurfaceView, implements SurfaceHolder.Callback);

```
enemy = new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy_pic));
```

Within the Enemy class, our image is declared as an instance variable;

```
private Bitmap image;
```

And then we initialise it in the constructor (picResource is the first argument into the constructor);

```
image = picResource;
```

My question is the following - if I create a list of enemy objects (there are lots of enemies!), will this result in the duplication of the Bitmap data? I am not sure from the docs whether it's lower level implementation will emulate pointer behaviour in C, and as such result in only minimal overhead from structuring it this way, or whether I am chewing up memory because I am essentially duplicating all the data in the picture file.

Comment: It won't. If you are not making any changes to the bitmap object, all the list items will reference the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create a list of enemy objects (there are lots of enemies!), will this result in the duplication of the Bitmap data?

Every call to [`decodeResource()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java#L459) will result in result in a new in-memory bitmap. If you create all your enemies as in your question:

```
enemy = new Enemy(
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy_pic)
);
```

every `Enemy` object will have its own unique bitmap.

That is, if you put this in a loop

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nEnemies; ++i) {
   enemy = new Enemy(
       BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy_pic)
   );
   enemies.add(enemy);
}
```

You will get `nEmemies` bitmaps, i.e. each `Enemy` object has its own (in-memory) bitmap.

If you decode your enemy bitmap only once and pass the resulting reference to the `Enemy` constructor, you just create new reference to the single existing bitmap. That is, rewriting the above as (for example)

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
Bitmap enemyBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enemy_pic);
for (int i = 0; i < nEnemies; ++i) {
   enemy = new Enemy(enemyBitmap);
   enemies.add(enemy);
}
```

results in only a *single* bitmap to be shared by all enemies (unless `Enemy` does something to the bitmap to create a copy).

To refer back to your answer. In Java, assignments of the form

```
image = picResource;
```

do not create copies, but only create additional references (to be precise, this is only true for reference types, i.e. objects).

Side note: if you use [`Context.getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable%28int%29), you can make use of use of Android's drawable cache and get the same drawable even for repeated calls.

Comment: Can you explain your answer more clearly it is confusing I understand the first code in your answer , that it will create new Bitmap resource for every enemy if used that way , but not after that